# how to search in a java file using java?

Tags: java, reflection

I need to search for a string (actually a method call) in a java file. I also need to know where it was called (I mean in which method in the java file). What is the best approach?

Comment: Java file, or class file?  If it's the former, and you care at all about reliability of the results, you're gonna need to parse Java.  Or get a compiler to do it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to search for a string in the source code, or find a method via Reflection at runtime? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Adam: `grep` couldn't catch uses of `(some Widget).toString()`, for example.  It could look for `toString()`, but that'd return every use of a function named `toString` anywhere in the app.  It couldn't find uses of *a particular class's* `toString`.  Short version: `grep` would only be useful if the method were very uniquely named and not overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection really only can tell you what methods and fields exist for a given Java object. By the time that the JVM is running, Java source has been compiled down to bytecode, and "searching for a string" in a source file is meaningless.

Best bet I would think is just to parse it like a regular text file.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Test {
   void doTest(){
    // do test
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      for (Method each : Test.class.getMethods()){
         System.out.println(each.getName() + "()");
      }
   }
}
```

Will return:
"doTest()"

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question.  Can you elaborate?